# $A(\textbf{r})= \textbf{r}\times \nabla\phi(\textbf{r})$ is orthogonal to $\textbf{r}$ and $\nabla\phi(\textbf{r})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, cross-product, index-notation

Let ${\textbf{r}} = (x,y,z)$ be the position vector. Show that the vector field $A(\textbf{r})= \textbf{r}\times \nabla\phi(\textbf{r})$ is orthogonal to $\textbf{r}$ and $\nabla\phi(\textbf{r})$, that is, the following expressions are true : $A(\textbf{r})\cdot \textbf{r} = 0$ and $A(\textbf{r})\cdot \nabla\phi(\textbf{r}) = 0$.

I managed to prove this  by direct application of the definitions in cartesian coordinates.

$\textbf{Now I am trying to do it using index notation since my professor required it }$:

$A(\textbf{r})\cdot \textbf{r} = (\textbf{r}\times \nabla\phi(\textbf{r})) \cdot \textbf{r} = \epsilon_{ijk}\textbf{r}_j\partial_k\phi\textbf{r}_i$ and $A(\textbf{r})\cdot \nabla\phi(\textbf{r}) =(\textbf{r}\times \nabla\phi(\textbf{r}))\cdot \nabla\phi(\textbf{r}) = \epsilon_{ijk}\textbf{r}_j\partial_k\phi\partial_i\phi $.

But I am not sure how to proceed from here, I can't see how these two expressions are going to be zero.

Any help will be appreciated . Thank you

Comment: $A=\epsilon_{ijk}a_ia_j b_k=0$ (summation over repeated indices is implied) for any arbitrary $\vec a=(a_i)=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ - just apply permutation of $i$ and $j$ (gives minus to $A$ due to antisymmetry of $\epsilon_{ijk}$), or rename $i\to j$ and $j\to i$ (does not change $A$ - these are dumb indices of summation which you can name as you want). $A=-A=0$

Comment: Why not use the property $a \cdot (a \times b) = (a \times a) \cdot b \ $? Or write determinant whose two rows will be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) (which can be proved using the Levi Civita Symbol, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977486/vector-product-and-dot-product-identity-levi-civita-symbols) ) we have that :

$ \textbf{1 -}A(\textbf{r})\cdot \nabla\phi(\textbf{r}) = (\textbf{r} \times \nabla\phi(\textbf{r}))\cdot \nabla\phi(\textbf{r}) = (\nabla\phi(\textbf{r})\times \nabla\phi(\textbf{r}))\cdot\textbf{r} = 0\cdot\textbf{r} = 0 $

Similarly:

$ \textbf{2-} A(\textbf{r})\cdot \textbf{r} = (\textbf{r}\times \nabla\phi(\textbf{r}))\cdot \textbf{r} = (\textbf{r}\times\textbf{r})\cdot \nabla\phi(\textbf{r}) = 0 \cdot \nabla\phi(\textbf{r}) = 0 $

From $\textbf{1}$ and $\textbf{2}$ we have the orthogonality.

Comment: So the symbol notation was used not directly as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to do any of that, since the cross product $v\times w$ of two vectors $v$ and $w$ is always orthogonal to both $v$ and to $w$.

Comment: I know that but the exercise is asking me to verify it.